# How to replace characters in a file utf8 in perl?

Tags: perl, unicode

I have something like this (it works):

```
perl -C -MText::Unidecode -n -i -e'print unidecode( $_)' unicode_text.txt
```

and now i want to do the same in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -CSA

use utf8;
use Text::Unidecode;


while(<>)
{
    print unidecode($_);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should `use strict;`.

Comment: `use utf8` serves no purpose here: you don't use utf-8 characters in the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It works for me.

Comment: In file i have "ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ" and i want to get "acelnoszzACELNOSZZ", but I got "AAAAAA3AAoA1/4AAAAAAAA1A>>
"

Comment: Your one-liner produces no output for me using Perl 5.20 and Text::Unidecode v0.04.  However, there is at least one issue I spot when I attempt to run your full sample code.  This line: `#!/usr/bin/perl -w -CSA` produces an error message: `Too late for "-CSA" option at......`  I believe the `-CSA` can be replaced in the script with `use open ':encoding(utf8)';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have got the error message

```
Too late for "-CSA" option
```

which is what makes the program read the input file as UTF-8-encoded.

Instead you need to put

```
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
```

before the `while` loop, which does the same as `-CS` on the command line, i.e. to set the `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` handles to UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Does that result in you getting some output from his script? I would have posted this answer, but haven't been able to get Text::Unidecode to do anything useful... at least when used with Perl5.20.

Comment: @DavidO: I am on version 20 and it works fine. I presume you've put a file name in `@ARGV`?